# Using a Random class in a static way

Tags: c++, class, random, static

I am making a simple `Random` class:

```
class Random
{
public:
    static bool seeded = false;

    static void SeedRandom( int number )
    {
        srand(number);
    }
    static int GetRandom(int low, int high)
    {
        if ( !seeded )
        {
            srand ((int)time(NULL));
        }
        return (rand() % (high - low)) + low;
    }
};
```

Obviously C++ doesn't allow a whole class to be declared as `static` (which is what makes this so easy in C#). I've instead made all the members as `static`. There is also no `static` constructor so I have no way to initialize my `bool seeded` unless I call a function by hand, which defeats the purpose. I can instead use a regular constructor in which I would have to create an instance of `Random`, which I don't want to do.

Also, does anyone know if the new C++0x standard will allow static classes and/or static constructors?

Comment: The `bool seeded = false` bit in your class is not valid. Only static **const** intergal members may be initialized in the body of a class that way. You must declare `seeded` seperately and initalize it at the declaration point (rather than the definition point).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> c++ doesn't allow declaring a whole class as static

Of course it does.

```
class RandomClass
{
public:
    RandomClass()
    {
        srand(time(0));
    }
    int NextInt(int high, int low)
    {
        return (rand() % (high - low)) + low;
    }
}

RandomClass Random; //Global variable "Random" has static storage duration

//C# needs to explicitly allow this somehow because C# does not have global variables,
//which is why it allows applying the static keyword to a class. But this is not C#,
//and we have globals here. ;)
```

Really though, there's no reason to put this in a class. C++ does not force you to put everything in classes -- for good reason. In C# you are forced to put everything into a class and declare things in static methods and such, but *that is not ideomatic C++*.

You really can't just take ideomatic C# code, and write that in C++, and expect it to work well. They are very different languages with very different requirements and programming characteristics.

If you want an ideomatic C++ way to do this, don't make a class at all. Call `srand` inside your `main`, and define a function that does your clamping:

```
int RandomInteger(int high, int low)
{
    return (std::rand() % (high - low)) + low;
}
```

**EDIT**: Of course, it would be better for you to use the new random number generation facility and `uniform_int_distribution` to get your clamped range instead of `rand`. See [`rand()` considered harmful](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful).

Comment: To say that the Random variable has a static storage is not entirely accurate for C++.  As it is defined above, it is a global variable (which is probably what is required).  A static variable would have local scope in the module in which it was defined.

Comment: @Blazes: Global variables have static storage duration in C++. C++ defines 3 storage durations (well, `thread` storage duration was added in C++11): `automatic` ("stack allocated" variables), `static` (global variables, and local `static` variables), and `dynamic` (allocated with `malloc` or `new`). Automatic variables live until the end of their block, dynamic variables live until `delete` or `free` is called on them, and static variables live until the program terminates.

Comment: @Blazes: To be clear, static storage duration has **nothing** to do with the `static` keyword. (It's detailed in section 3.7 in my copy of the standard...)

Comment: thanks for pointing that out.  You are right.  The use of the word 'static' is being used to describe both 'storage duration' and 'linkage'.  Global variables have 'static storage duration'.  but imo - the use of 'static' to describe storage duration for globals, and also to describe linkage is confusing.

Comment: @Blazes: Agreed. I don't make the rules, I just follow 'em.

Answer (score 2):

Your `static bool seeded` will need to be defined in a cpp file anyway, and you must initialise it there.

```
bool Random::seeded = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to make everything a class in C++.

```
namespace Random 
{ 
    bool seeded = false;

    void SeedRandom(int number)
    { srand(number); }

    int GetRandom(int low, int high)
    {         
        if (!seeded)
        { srand((int)time(NULL)); }

       return (rand() % (high - low)) + low; 
   }    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Random
{
public:
    static bool seeded;

    static void SeedRandom(int number)
    {
        srand(number);
        seeded = true;
    }

    static int GetRandom(int low, int high)
    {
        if (!seeded)
            SeedRandom(time(0));
        return (rand() % (high - low)) + low;
    }
};

bool Random::seeded;
```

`static` `bool`s get initialized to `false` by default, so no need to do so explicitly. Note that your actual class' logic was wrong as well, as you never set `seeded` to `true`.

Comment: This is a good class, but you are wrong about Random::seeded being initialized to 'false' by default.  In debug mode, it will be set to 'false', but in release, it will have a random value unless specifically initialized.  Always initialize member variables.

Comment: @Blazes : `seeded` is not a member variable, it is `static`. From the C++03 standard, §9.4.2/7: "*Static data members are initialized and destroyed exactly like non-local objects (3.6.2, 3.6.3).*". From §3.6.2/1: "*Objects with static storage duration (3.7.1) shall be zero-initialized (8.5) before any other initialization
takes place.*" So, `seeded` will **always** be zero-initialized, which for `bool` of course means `false` -- the standard mandates it.

Comment: Why make it a class and not a namespace when everything is public and static? Sometimes the answer to "How do I do this?" is "Don't do that!". ("Doctor, doctor - it hurts when I do this!").

Answer (score 0):

You could always approach this with a singleton pattern, by having the constructor private and a static accessor for the object.

```
class Random
{
 public:
  static Random& instance()
  {
    static Random instance;

    return instance;
  }

  // your other functions here

 private:
  Random()
  {
    // your seed code here
  }    
};
```

This will ensure you only have a single instance of the class and whenever you need a random you just need to call Random::instance().function()

Comment: Don't see much reason to create a singleton (your class Random) for another singleton (std::rand / std::srand).

Comment: The same logic could be applied as to why use another class at all, it just provides a single instance global access wrapper, that can be extended with whatever functionality the user needs.

Comment: And I would argue that one shouldn't use another class here. C++ does not require everything to be in a class. Programming that way is not using the language effectively.

Comment: I'm not sure that a singleton (at least stricto sensu) is appropriate here.  (I can see using something that looks very much like a singleton to manage order of initialization, **if** the object might be used in the constructor of a static variable.  But that seems unlikely to me, and in many cases, I imagine that you'd want to get the seed from a command line argument.)

Comment: @Billy I agree another possible solution for this would then be not to use a class at all and simply namespace these static functions and variable.

Answer (score 0):

What is the reason for you to have a class with static methods? May be there is an alternate to achieve your goal. Are you looking for something SIMILAR to singleton?

BTW if you have static members variables in your class declaration, as pointed out by other answers before me, you must initialize them outside the class (preferably in the cpp file) before you use them. So if you follow this and initialize your like this:

```
  bool Random::seeded = false
```

it will be automatically initialized to false as you want.